# does the optimize table of mysql really rebuild(recreate) table？

Tags: mysql

I have a question about optimize table of mysql,I have read many documents about this function,all of the document says：it can  defragment an InnoDB table and reorganizes the physical storage of table data and associated index data, to reduce storage space,but no one can tell me the principle of optimize table and slove my questions,I have known those informations:

1. As of MySQL 5.6.17,OPTIMIZE TABLE uses online DDL for regular and partitioned InnoDB tables
2. ,As of MySQL 5.6.17,The table rebuild triggered by OPTIMIZE TABLE and performed under the cover by ALTER TABLE ... FORCE is completed in place(ALGORITHM =inplace)

my questions:

1. does the optimize table of mysql really rebuild(recreate) table？ because it completed in place(not ALGORITHM=copy),is ALGORITHM=inplace real rebuild(recreate) table?

thank you for your response.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBvq4.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Demo:

I created a table on MySQL 5.6.37 and filled it with about 1GB of random data.

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------------+
| version()       |
+-----------------+
| 5.6.37-82.2-log |
+-----------------+

mysql> show table status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: mytable
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Compact
           Rows: 61914
 Avg_row_length: 20926
    Data_length: 1295613952
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 1589248
      Data_free: 4194304
 Auto_increment: 131056
    Create_time: 2019-02-20 15:54:23
    Update_time: NULL
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: utf8mb4_general_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options: 
        Comment:
```

I can observe the file in my datadir and note the inode number (the leftmost number).

```
/usr/local/var/mysql/test ls -li
total 2590752
8625784850 -rw-rw----  1 bkarwin  admin          67 Feb 20 07:54 db.opt
8625784853 -rw-rw----  1 bkarwin  admin        8580 Feb 20 07:54 mytable.frm
8625784854 -rw-rw----  1 bkarwin  admin  1321205760 Feb 20 07:56 mytable.ibd
```

I run optimize table.

```
mysql> optimize table mytable;
```

While it's running, I check progress by listing files in the datadir again. I see it has created a new temp file and it's filling it with a copy of the data.

Note the inode number of the temp file.

```
/usr/local/var/mysql/test ls -li
total 4395064
8625785082 -rw-rw----  1 bkarwin  admin        8580 Feb 20 07:57 #sql-337_16.frm
8625785083 -rw-rw----  1 bkarwin  admin   914358272 Feb 20 07:57 #sql-ib2021-3689447301.ibd
8625784850 -rw-rw----  1 bkarwin  admin          67 Feb 20 07:54 db.opt
8625784853 -rw-rw----  1 bkarwin  admin        8580 Feb 20 07:54 mytable.frm
8625784854 -rw-rw----  1 bkarwin  admin  1321205760 Feb 20 07:56 mytable.ibd
```

Finally my optimize table finishes. It took almost 2 minutes. If it wasn't doing a real table copy, why would it have taken so long?

```
+--------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table        | Op       | Msg_type | Msg_text                                                          |
+--------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| test.mytable | optimize | note     | Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead |
| test.mytable | optimize | status   | OK                                                                |
+--------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (1 min 5.52 sec)
```

Looking at the datadir again, I see the temp file has been renamed to be the new tablespace, and the old file has been removed. The new file has the inode number of the temp file, indicating it's the copy.

```
/usr/local/var/mysql/test ls -li
total 2557984
8625784850 -rw-rw----  1 bkarwin  admin          67 Feb 20 07:54 db.opt
8625785082 -rw-rw----  1 bkarwin  admin        8580 Feb 20 07:57 mytable.frm
8625785083 -rw-rw----  1 bkarwin  admin  1304428544 Feb 20 07:58 mytable.ibd
```

Comment: Thank you very very very much,I never think about inode,i will do my own test again,that is a good way to solve related issues